# Add file and text to another file c#

Tags: c#

I want to copy content from one file to another. In addition to this I also want to add a default text before and after this content.

I have found the following method for file to file:

```
    public void MergeFile(String path1, string path2)
    {
        var text1 = "Text";
        var text2 = "Another text";

        using (FileStream source1 = File.Open(path1, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (FileStream source2 = File.Open(path2, FileMode.Open))
            {
                source1.CopyTo(source2);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want text1 at the start of the file and text2 as the last line in the file. Can anyone give some advice on how to do this?

I want the solution to be as fast as possible since the source1 content may be several thousand lines long.

Thank you.

Comment: This is  not that difficult there are several ways to do this .. you should look at the following functionality in regards to writing and or appending text to an existing file as well as another file `WriteLine` frunction if you need a simple example of a quick function I will post one for you.. you are pretty close with what you have but I personally would refactor it into a Method that checks if the file does not exist, then write to the file else create a FileStream and use the WriteLine method let me know if you need the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Stream.CopyTo` is probably your best bet here.  Just call `FileStream.Write` before and after:

```
var text1 = "Text";
var text2 = "Another text";
using (FileStream source1 = File.Open(source1, FileMode.Open))
{
   using (FileStream source2 = File.Open(source2, FileMode.Open))
   {
       source2.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text1), 0, text1.Length);
       source1.CopyTo(source2);
       source2.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text2), 0, text2.Length);
   }
}
```

Couple things to note:

- This will not add newline characters as is (add a `\r\n` to the end of your strings if you need that)
- This will overwrite existing files as is (use a different `FileMode` if you don't want that)
- This will not create new files as is (use a different  `FileMode` if this isn't desired)

Comment: Yes, as far as I know the Stream.CopyTo is a safe bet, but I tried some variants of this solution without any luck. This one does the trick. Thank you.

It should also be said that the file check does not happen here and I want the file to be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an existing file then append to it you could you the exiting method below.. very simple to understand

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string path = @"C:\FileWrite_Append\SomeFile.txt";

  if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
  {
    WriteAndOrAppendText(path, "Text");
  }
  else if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
  {
    WriteAndOrAppendText(path, "Another Text");             
  }
}

private static void WriteAndOrAppendText(string path, string strText)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        StreamWriter fileStream = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        fileStream.WriteLine(strText);
        fileStream.Flush();
        fileStream.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        StreamWriter fileStream2 = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        fileStream2.WriteLine(strText);
        fileStream2.Flush();
        fileStream2.Close();
    }
}
```